# Eliminate rows from a result set based on column value occurrence

Tags: sql, mariadb

After executing a long SQL query with many joins, I get a result set similar to the following:

```
A   B     C     D     E
foo bar   baz   cat   123
dog lorem ipsum dolor 123
bar baz   foo   dog   456
cat amet  bar   baz   789
```

I would like to eliminate rows from the result set where the occurrence of column value E is less than 2. Effectively, it would make the end result look like the following:

```
A   B     C     D     E
foo bar   baz   cat   123
dog lorem ipsum dolor 123
```

I have tried variations of sub-queries, GROUP BY clauses, WHERE expressions, and COUNT() expressions but cannot transform the data to get the result I want.

My SQL isn't the greatest. For various reasons, solving this problem in SQL instead of manipulating the result set in Java is preferable.

Is something like this possible in SQL?

Performance is not yet a major concern as the original result sets tend to be small.

Using a MariaDB database.

Comment: What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is window functions:

```
select q.*
from (select q.*, count(*) over (partition by e) as cnt
      from <your query here> q
     ) q
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This works well and will come in handy in the future.